# ASP.NET TableCell OnSelected?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tablecell

So, I have to create a list of items from a database, and I usually do that with a GridView; however, this client requires that while they select an item from the list, it automatically displays the item's picture elsewhere.

So, I created the table, and I create rows from the code behind to fill it.

This is the table:

```
<asp:Table ID="tblWatches" CssClass="table table-striped" runat="server" Width="50%" BorderStyle="Double" BorderColor="Black">
    <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server">
        <asp:TableCell ID="tblCell1">
            <asp:Label ID="code" runat="server" Text="code"></asp:Label>                
        </asp:TableCell>

        <asp:TableCell ID="tblCell2">
            <asp:Label ID="stock" runat="server" Text="stock"></asp:Label>                
        </asp:TableCell>

        <asp:TableCell ID="tblCell3">
            <asp:Label ID="purchased" runat="server" Text="purchased"></asp:Label>                
        </asp:TableCell>

        <asp:TableCell ID="tblCell4">
            <asp:Label ID="price" runat="server" Text="price"></asp:Label>                
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

On the code behind, I create the rows like this:

```
DataView view;
view = getWatches();

TableRow rowNew;
TableCell cellNew;
Label lblNew; 

for (int i = 0; i < view.Count; i++)
{       
    rowNew = new TableRow();
    tblWatches.Rows.Add(rowNew);

    cellNew = new TableCell();            
    lblNew = new Label();
    lblNew.Text = Convert.ToString(view[i][1]);
    cellNew.TabIndex = Convert.ToInt16(i + 1);  
    cellNew.Controls.Add(lblNew);
    rowNew.Cells.Add(cellNew);


    cellNew = new TableCell();
    lblNew = new Label();
    lblNew.Text = Convert.ToInt32(view[i][2]).ToString();   
    cellNew.Controls.Add(lblNew);
    rowNew.Cells.Add(cellNew);


    cellNew = new TableCell();
    lblNew = new Label();
    lblNew.Text = Convert.ToString(view[i][3]); 
    cellNew.Controls.Add(lblNew);
    rowNew.Cells.Add(cellNew);

    cellNew = new TableCell();
    lblNew = new Label();
    lblNew.Text = Convert.ToString(view[i][4]); 
    cellNew.Controls.Add(lblNew);
    rowNew.Cells.Add(cellNew);
}
```

That works perfectly. It created the rows, and I can cycle through them with the Tab key. The thing is, now I want to be able to use the "onselect" event, so when the client cycles through the items, the image box is updated.
But the TableCell doesn't have that event. Is there a workaround? Is this at all possible?

P.S.: Why the tab-cycling? They want the list to feel like an Excel spreadsheet, where you can move through the items with the arrow keys. The closest I've managed to do was the TabIndex.

Comment: Try to add event on the Table itself. Then get the ID of the specific cell clicked/selected.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Sorry about that. I had no idea! Will keep that in mind for future reference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TableCell` type as you mentioned has no `OnSelected` event, so the easiest option is to tackle it in the front-end with jQuery by binding an on focus event to the table cells:

```
$(function() {
    $("table[id$=tblWatches] tr td").on( "focus", function() {
        var code = $(this).parent("tr").find("td:first-child > label").text();
        // set img src here
    });
});
```

Then depending on where the image files are stored, use the product code to set the `src` path on the `<img>`. i.e. `"/images/products/" + code + ".jpg"` or a handler `"/productimage.ashx?code=" + code`

Comment: I'm having an issue now, and I can't get my head around it. The "code" variable is returning nothing at all. I changed that commented line for an alert("The code is: " + code + "."); and it's returning a blank space where code should be. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: If you have another problem it's usually considered best to start another question, as the problem is probably more to do with the current state of your code rather than the original issue. Most likely though it'll have something to do with the jQuery selectors.